# Basic PHP Array Iteration Issue

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I hate to be one of "those guys" - I'm very sure the answer is right in front of my face and I simply can't grasp it. However I have tried for the last few hours to figure this out with the help of our friend Mr. Google to no avail.

What I am trying to do is quite simple:

1. Push a string to an array.
2. Count through the entries in the array X number of times with an offset, and return the resulting value as a variable.

For all my labor, I have just this:

```
$newarray = array(1,2,3,4,7,5,8,6,9);
```

I'd like to be able to count (for example) starting at the number 3, increment by a variable number (for example, 12) in something of a round robin manner. This would put the end of the count at the number 5. I'd then like to take that number (5) and store it in a variable for use on the rest of the page.

Again, I know this should be elementary but for whatever reason I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try iterators http://php.net/manual/pl/class.iterator.php

Comment: Where is your trial code?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the intended behavior? To me, it's not clear what the iteration should accomplish.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a sort of random number?

Comment: can i seen your trial code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I don't have the trial code for this as I haven't been able to even figure out what I need to use to accomplish the goal.

For people using the application, the system will take their age in years and iterate through the string above by those years. So 20 years would be 20 hops from one number to the next. I need it to be able to count twenty times and then show the value of the number the end of the count lands on. I'm sorry if I'm failing to convey my point concisely.

Comment: @JohnDoe Check if the answer work for you

Comment: @JohnDoe You should put that above comment in the question. Also, are you submitting a form to get the input for age? Or where is age stored?

Comment: There is a form submission for the birth date, determining the person's current age is as simple as:

$fulldob = $byear."-".$bmonth."-".$bday;
$currentage = floor((time() - strtotime($fulldob)) / 31556926);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the way:

1. Changing the position of the desired element to first position
2. Finally, pick the element which you desire after a circulating through the array.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
function circulateArr($key, $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $arrkey => $value)
    {
        if($arrkey != $key)
        {
            $elm = array_shift($arr);
            array_push($arr, $elm);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}


$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$start = 3;
$roundRobin = 12;

$arr = circulateArr(array_search($start, $array), $array); //Repositioning the array

echo $elementChose = $arr[($roundRobin%count($arr))-1]; //Get the array element
```

Output:

5

Comment: I believe it works now... Give me a few to double check and if it turns out right I'll mark your's as the answer.

Comment: You sir are a god among men - thank you very much for both your help, and also the new studying material!

Comment: Glad that I helped you.. Thank God :D

Answer (score 0):

For your number 1 you will want to use array_push() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php .

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
?>
```

This will display

```
Array
(
[0] => orange
[1] => banana
[2] => apple
[3] => raspberry
)
```

For your number 2.  You can use a simple for loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i< $stack.count(); $i++){
    $tmp = $stack[$i];
    //tmp will be the value at that location do what you will with it
}
```

For the offset, just set $i to your offset

```
for($i = $offset; $i < $stack.count(); $i++){
    $tmp = $stack[$i];
    //tmp will be the value at that location do what you will with it
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the value that I was hoping to return from such a loop would be the number that the count ends on in the array, and not all of the values from the array.

As an example, I want PHP to play inne menni miny mo with the array, and catch the value of the last iteration. So in your example above, I would like for PHP to count through the fruit array values five times with an offset of 1. So we would start at banana and count through the array by five, which would put us at apple. I'd like the code to then store "apple" as a variable that could be used for the rest of the page.

Comment: @JohnDoe Do these number 1 and 5 change? If so how?

Comment: They do change. Number 1 being the offset, is calculated on a per-person basis and changes based on the day of the week a person was born, as does the number 5 representing the person's age in years.

Answer (score 0):

1) Push a string to an array can be done with array_push.

2) Counting through the entries in the array X number of times with an offset, and return the resulting value as a variable is a little more complicated.  We can use count() and add 1 to get the number of elements in an array and compute the ordinal key offset using the PHP modulus operator %  If the array is not already keyed with ordinal values, array_value() will rekey the array with ordinal values for us. Then we just return the value.

Below is a small bit of code that pulls it all together for you.

```
    <?php
    $myArray = array(1,2,3,4,7,5,8,6);
    array_push($myArray,'9'); 
    $start=3;
    $increment=12;

    echo roundRobbinArrayValue($myArray,$start+$increment)."\n";

    function  roundRobbinArrayValue($myArray,$pointer){
        $ordinalArray=array_values($myArray);
        $numberOfItems=count($ordinalArray)+1; 
        $newPointer= $pointer % $numberOfItems;
        return $ordinalArray[$newPointer];      
    }  
    ?>
```